Pointer inconsistency in modified Queue struct template using AVL
I'm making a modified Queue struct template using AVL tree to allow for moving elements forward. If I use normal linked list implementation, moving a given element forward by x positions will cos O(n), hence why I want to use AVL.
I keep pointers to head (the leftmost node) to be popped and tail (the rightmost) for last pushed. There is a function jump_forward(Ref node, k) which will move a node given by reference forward by k positions closer to head.
I'm having a problem in pop_first() function, resulting in seg faults.
I also unsure on how to implement keeping order of position (Node's position value should increment with its insertion so new node is always new max)
struct Node {
    T value;
    int position;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
    int depth;

Node(T val, int pos, Node* par = nullptr) : value(val), position(pos), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(par), depth(1) {}
};

struct Queue {
Node<T>* root;
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* tail;
size_t count;

Queue() : root(nullptr), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), count(0) {}
bool empty() const {
    return count == 0;
}
size_t size() const {
    return count;
}

struct Ref {
    Node<T>* node;
    Ref(Node<T>* n = nullptr) : node(n) {};
};

Ref push_last(T x) {
    // queue is empty -> create new node
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node(x, count++);
        head = tail = root;
    } else {
        // attach new node as right child of current max -> rebalance
        Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(x, count++, tail);
        tail->right = newNode;
        tail = newNode;

        Node<T> *tmp = newNode->parent;
        // re-balancing the right subtree
        while (tmp) {
            updateDepth(tmp);
            tmp = reBalance(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->parent;
        }
    }
    return Ref(tail);

};
T pop_first() {
    if (empty()) throw std::out_of_range("Queue is empty");

    T headValue = head->value;
    Node<T>* oldHead = head;

    // head is root -> last element
    if(head->right == nullptr && head->parent == nullptr) {
        root = nullptr;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        count = 0;
     // head is root but has right child
    } else if (head->right != nullptr && head->parent == nullptr) {
        head = head->right;
        head->parent = nullptr;
        root = head;
    // head is not root
    } else {
        // head has right child
        if (head->right) {
            head = head->right;
            head->parent = oldHead->parent;
            head->parent->left = head;
        // head has no right child
        } else {
            head = oldHead->parent;
            head->left = nullptr;
        }
    }
    delete oldHead;
    count--;

    if(root) {
        Node<T> *tmp = head->parent;
        // re-balancing the left subtree
        while (tmp) {
            updateDepth(tmp);
            tmp= reBalance(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->parent;
        }
    }
    return headValue;
}; // throw std::out_of_range if empty

int getDepth(Node<T> *node) const {
    return node ? node->depth : 0;
}
void updateParent(Node<T>* child, Node<T>* parent) {
    if (child) {
        child->parent = parent;
    }
}
void updateDepth(Node<T> *node) {
    if (node) {
        node->depth = std::max(getDepth(node->left), getDepth(node->right)) + 1;
    }
}
int getBalanceFactor(Node<T>* node) const {
    if (!node) return 0;
    return getDepth(node->left) - getDepth(node->right);
}
Node<T>* rightRotate(Node<T>* y) {
    Node<T>* x = y->left;
    Node<T>* T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    updateParent(T2, y);
    updateParent(x, y->parent);
    updateParent(y, x);

    if (y == root) {
        root = x;
        x->parent = nullptr;
    }
    updateDepth(y);
    updateDepth(x);

    return x;
}

Node<T>* leftRotate(Node<T>* x) {
    Node<T>* y = x->right;
    Node<T>* T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    updateParent(T2, x);
    updateParent(y, x->parent);
    updateParent(x, y);

    if (x == root) {
        root = y;
        y->parent = nullptr;
    }

    updateDepth(x);
    updateDepth(y);

    return y;
}

Node<T>* reBalance(Node<T>* node) {

    int balance = getBalanceFactor(node);

    // Right heavy
    if (balance > 1) {
        if (getBalanceFactor(node->left) < 0)
            node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node); }

    // Left heavy
    if (balance < -1) {
        if (getBalanceFactor(node->right) > 0)
            node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }
    return node;
}
};


First task to solve pointer-problems is to simplify your code. Remove large pieces of code until it works as expected. Then add back one line at a time until the error comes back. Using the information you get from that you create a [mre] that you can debug. While using the debugger use pencil and paper to draw all operations with the pointers, using arrows for the pointers and labeled boxes for variables/nodes.

And for future programs, start with the pencil and paper, to help you visualize what you need to do. Then when implementing the design, do it in very small pieces, perhaps just writing one or two lines at a time. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors, and test the code before adding the next small bit of code.

A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example is also helpful for those attempting to help with your question.

Do you realise that the standard library template std::map provides all the functionality of an AVL tree? Unless you are coding this as a learning exercise then there is no point in reinventing the wheel.
